# Python Dataframe: Remove Rows from Dataframe Using a Loop

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, rows

I wanted to remove certain rows from my pandas dataframe.  I did it the manual way of spelling out each ITEM number that I didn't want included.

How do I do the same task as shown in the code below but using a loop?

```
df_adhoc_1_final = df_adhoc_1_final[df_adhoc_1_final['ITEM'].str.contains('4888') == False]
df_adhoc_1_final = df_adhoc_1_final[df_adhoc_1_final['ITEM'].str.contains('4889') == False]
df_adhoc_1_final = df_adhoc_1_final[df_adhoc_1_final['ITEM'].str.contains('4890') == False]
df_adhoc_1_final = df_adhoc_1_final[df_adhoc_1_final['ITEM'].str.contains('4891') == False]
df_adhoc_1_final = df_adhoc_1_final[df_adhoc_1_final['ITEM'].str.contains('4892') == False]
df_adhoc_1_final = df_adhoc_1_final[df_adhoc_1_final['ITEM'].str.contains('4893') == False]
```

Comment: Generally, if you are using loops with DFs, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the accepted answer. You should avoid using a loop where possible. Keep in mind that they're not only more cumbersome, but inefficient compared to .str.contains or .isin

Comment: If you were aiming to solve another problem where you can't use anything besides a loop, you should probably re-evaluate your strategy, because you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about:

```
for val in ['4888','4889','4890','4891','4892','4893']:
    df_adhoc_1_final = df_adhoc_1_final[df_adhoc_1_final['ITEM'].str.contains(val) == False]
```

Comment: No, I don't condone this. Please avoid a loop as much as possible when working with pandas.

Comment: agreed. But my answer had to be different from yours. Hence.

Answer (score 1):

A loop is unnecessary here. There is almost always a vectorised, non-loopy approach with any pandas operation. Here's one way to do it.

First, initialise a list of codes -

```
codes = ['4888', '4889', ... '4893']
```

Or,

```
codes = np.arange(4888, 4894).astype(str)
```

Now, filter using `str.contains`. You'll need to join each code as a single regex using the `|` OR pipe -

```
df = df[~df['ITEM'].str.contains('|'.join(codes))]
```

If the codes are the only thing in the `ITEM` column, you can use `isin` -

```
df = df[~df['ITEM'].isin(codes)]
```